# Latency time difference when use parallel::forkmanager in Perl

Tags: perl, benchmarking, www-mechanize

I am using the Google website just to explain my problem.

I have a webpage with a form. I am using [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) to fetch and fill the form, noting the start time in `$s1`.

I am reading the title on the next page and noting end time in `$s2`.

Then I calculate the wait time by `$s2 - $s1`.

This is my code

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Time::HiRes qw/gettimeofday/;
use Time::Format qw/%time/;
use POSIX qw( strftime );
use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday );

$m = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$m->get( "http://www.google.com" );
$m->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    fields      => { q => 'abcd' },
);

$s1 = gettimeofday;
my ($secs, $microsecs) = gettimeofday();
print strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime($secs)) . sprintf(".%04d", $microsecs/10);

print " ";
print $m->title;
print " ";

$s2 = gettimeofday;
my ($secs, $microsecs) = gettimeofday();
print strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime($secs)) . sprintf(".%04d", $microsecs/10);

$s3 = $s2 - $s1;
$s3 = $s3 * 1000;
print "  $s3\n";
```

The output is:

```
18:02:42.71923 abcd - Google Search 18:02:42.71996  0.737905502319336
```

Now, i used same code in Parallel Fork Manager keeping loopcount as 1.
My code:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Time::HiRes qw/gettimeofday/;
use Time::Format qw/%time/;
use POSIX qw( strftime );
use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday );

$count = 1;

$pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($count);

for ( 1 .. $count ) {

  $pm->start and next;

  $m = WWW::Mechanize->new();
  $m->get( "http://www.google.com" );
  $m->submit_form(
      form_number => 1,
      fields      => { q => 'abcd' },
  );

  $s1 = gettimeofday;
  my ($secs, $microsecs) = gettimeofday();
  print strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime($secs)) . sprintf(".%04d", $microsecs/10);

  print " ";
  print $m->title;
  print " ";

  $s2 = gettimeofday;
  my ($secs, $microsecs) = gettimeofday();
  print strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime($secs)) . sprintf(".%04d", $microsecs/10);

  $s3 = $s2 - $s1;
  $s3 = $s3 * 1000;
  print "  $s3\n";

  $pm->finish
}  

$pm->wait_all_children; ## wait for the child processes
```

My output:

```
18:02:48.55297 abcd - Google Search 18:02:48.55325  0.282049179077148
```

I am not able to understand why there is so much difference in Latency time when use fork(reduce to 1/3). It should be same. Any idea. My main purpose is to record Latency time for 1000-2000 requests and find average. Since there is so much difference between direct code and same code under fork, i am not sure if Latency time is correct.

Comment: While not related to the problem, check out [Benchmark](https://metacpan.org/pod/Benchmark), it's the core module to meassure stuff.

Comment: `strict` and `warnings` are also highly recommended.

Comment: I can't actually reproduce you problem. If you set the ForkManager value to `0`, it shouldn't actually `fork()` at all, running the code normally (because `next` doesn't execute).

Comment: Do you realise that you're not measuring the time taken by the web request? All that happens between the two times is a few utility calls and four print statements. You're seeing times of 738μs and 282μs which are far too small to assign any meaning to. Internet response times will be of the order of a second or so

Comment: @Borodin: my $t1 is time immediately after submitting form and then i am printing title of response page and then recording $t2. Is it not giving web request time?

Comment: @Sobrique: So you are getting same time for both the code? Try running few times.

Comment: The `submit_form` method call sends the request and waits for the response. It doesn't continue until you call `title` and then wait until it has the response information to print

Comment: I did. 10 iterations, pretty consistent results. But as Borodin notes - what you're _testing_ is the time taken to `print`, because you don't "start the clock" until after the request.

Comment: So, where should i put my $t1 and $t2? :( :( :(

Answer (score 3):

You aren't measuring the internet response time, you're just timing a few print statements and function calls. If you have an internet connection that responds within half a millisecond then I'm amazed!

Try this code, which does something similar but times the internet request/response round trip

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;
use Time::HiRes 'gettimeofday';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get( 'http://www.google.com/' );

my $t0 = gettimeofday;

$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    fields      => { q => 'abcd' },
);

my $t1 = gettimeofday;

printf "Title: %s\n",  $mech->title;
printf "Delay: %5.3fs\n", $t1 - $t0;
```

#### output

```
Title: abcd - Google Search
Delay: 1.784s
```

Comment: ok, so i need to put $t0 just before submit instead of immediately after submit. Right? Also, my application is calling an API on submit and printing  response code received from API on next page. So, i am using $m->content to get content, regex to read response code and then print response code and then noting $t1. Is my method correct?

Comment: @user3388005: If you're timing *only* the internet transaction then you want to grab the time before and after the `get` call (which may be a `submit_form` call or something similar) `$mech->content` uses only local data that has been retrieved, and you can get the response code using `$mech->res->code`